# Preserving connectivity from a vertex by edges deletion

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, graph-algorithms

Given a connected graph $G$ and a vertex $v$, is it polynomially solvable to find a maximal cardinality set of edges incident to $v$, which deletion (still) leaves vertex $v$ to be connected with all the other vertices in $G$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is an easy task. Remove $v$ and count the connected components, let $k$ be that number. Then at most $\deg(v)-k$ edges can be removed from $v$.

Comment: Sorry for not being completely clear in the question. Can these $\deg (v) -k$ edges be found in a polynomial time?

Comment: Just keep a single edge going from $v$ to each connected component...

Comment: I think you have been misled, this doesn't seem the right way to formulate the problem stated in the title; I would suggest looking at possible applications of the Gallai-Edmonds decomposition to your question (Thm 2.2.3 in Diestel's textbook).

Comment: @user17410 That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Construct a DFS traversal tree, starting from $v$.

You can remove all edges of v that are not part of the tree.

The tree construction costs $O(|V|+|E|)$.

The identification of the edges that can be removed is $O(deg(v))$.